# How to fix python build error "ValueError: no such test method in <class '__main__."

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

My python script is listed:

==========================================

```
class ExampleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    capabilities = None

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities={ "browserName": broswer,      "platform": platform, "node": node })

def test_example(self):
    self.driver.get("www.360logica.com")
    self.assertEqual(self.driver.title, "360logica")

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #unittest.main()
    args = sys.argv
    port = args[1]
    platform = args[2]
    broswer = args[3]
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(ExampleTestCase("test_example"))
    runner = XMLTestRunner(file('results_ExampleTestCase_%s.xml' % (broswer), "w"))
    runner.run(suite)
```

==============================================

The run command as:

```
$ ./python.exe Grid_1.py 5555 WINDOW firefox
```

==============================================

The build error log is:

```
$ ./python.exe Grid_1.py 5555 WINDOW firefox
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Grid_1.py", line 31, in <module>
        suite.addTest(ExampleTestCase("test_example"))
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 191, in __init__
        (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class '__main__.ExampleTestCase'>: test_example
```

===================================================

Please help me. I am so headache with that build error and don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have `suite.addTest(ExampleTestCase("test_example"))`, but your `def` is outside the scope of the class (if it is indeed your indentation). Make sure that test_example is part of the class.

```
class ExampleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    capabilities = None

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities={ "browserName": broswer, "platform": platform})

    def test_example(self):
        self.driver.get("www.360logica.com")
        self.assertEqual(self.driver.title, "360logica")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #unittest.main()
    args = sys.argv
    port = args[1]
    platform = args[2]
    broswer = args[3]
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(ExampleTestCase("test_example"))
    runner = XMLTestRunner(file('results_ExampleTestCase_%s.xml' % (broswer), "w"))
    runner.run(suite)
```

python substring.py 5555 WINDOW firefox
This ends up dumping the results (as expected) as results_ExampleTestCase_firefox.xml

Comment: Hi Gordon, I still have that build error when I tried to re-def the test_example as a part of class. But whatever I try I have that error again and again..... So headache... As you are an expert, can you help me where is the best place to def test_example? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know exactly what is happening here but there are a few things I can point out. In your `def setUp()` you call for `"node": node` but node is never listed anywhere. After fixing this I am able to run this with the commands you supplied, this is my output: http://pastebin.com/hFWmxiUe

Comment: The node is refer to a client machine what the test content will send to. But now it is useless for compiler. Can remove it. Also I saw the run log you already remove it and run completely without node. So you did re-def test_example as a part of class. Can I try your fix? I will buy you a lunch.

Comment: As try your fix to remove the node as you post inside of setup. Don't know the how. got the same error as my previous run. Beside of remove node: node, do you make some other change?

Comment: User@SC027042 ~/Python27/selenv/Scripts
$ ./python.exe Grid_1.py 5555 WINDOW firefox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Grid_1.py", line 32, in <module>
    suite.addTest(ExampleTestCase("test_example"))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 191, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class '__main__.ExampleTestCase'>: test_example

Comment: User@SC027042 ~/Python27/selenv/Scripts
$ ./python.exe Grid_1.py 5555 WINDOW firefox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Grid_1.py", line 32, in <module>
    suite.addTest(ExampleTestCase("test_example"))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 191, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class '__main__.ExampleTestCase'>: test_example

Comment: That sounds like some kind of copy/paste error. It's complaining that your `test_example` doesn't exist within `ExampleTestCase`, which usually points to some error with indentation.

Comment: Okay let me re-write this short program and see what happen. Thanks.